# Property of countably infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am having problems proving the following statement: 
"If E is a countably infinite set, therefore exist a countably infinite family of countably infinite subsets which meets the following requirements"
\begin{equation}
\lbrace E_i:E_i\subset E\ , \ i \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace
\\
 E_i\cap E_j=\emptyset , \ if \ i\neq j
\\
 E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\ E_j
\end{equation}

I suppose that I can start with something like:
\begin{equation}
E= \lbrace e_1 \ e_2 \ e_3 \ e_4 ....\rbrace 
\\
E_i=\lbrace a_{i1} \ a_{i2} \ a_{i3} \ a_{i4} ....\rbrace\\
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation} a_{in}=\lim_{j \to \infty}e_{i+jn}
\end{equation}
But I don't know how to continue or even if this is something valid to do

Comment: Notice that "countable" means "finite or countably infinite" (emphasis on the first option). I think you are assuming that $E_i$ has to be infinite, but it could also be finite. The hardest case to prove will be if $E$ is countably infinite, but you should also say what happens if $E$ is finite.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to be countably infinite $ E \sim \mathbb{N}$

Comment: This is purely a set-theoretical question; limits, analysis and topology don't come into it. Hint: Use the cardinality of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ (which includes $0$ in my view) to $E$, we just use some fixed bijection $b: \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ ( say $h(k,m)$ maps to  $2^k \cdot (2m+1)$ for concreteness), and then we just use $E_i = f[b[\Bbb N \times \{i\}]]$ as the required sets. Bijections preserve the disjointness..

Answer (score 1):

Always a good move to try simple options first.

How about the singleton sets $\{e\} \subseteq E$

Are they countable? Are they disjoint? What's their union?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to be countably infinite $E \sim \mathbb{N}$